# Deep copy of an ArrayList - method clone() is not visible

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement my own deep copy of this object:

```
public class Column<T extends Cloneable>
{

    private final ArrayList<T> values;

    private String name;

    // ...

}
```

This is how I would clone an instance of this class:

```
Column<String> column     = new Column<String>();
// ...
Column<String> columnCopy = column.copy();
```

This is the method that I'm trying to implement  (assuming that the method clone() is correcty ovverridden):

```
public Column<T> copy()
{
    ArrayList<T> valuesCopy = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (T value : values)
        valuesCopy.add(value.clone()); // The method clone() from the type Object is not visible

    return new Column<T>(name, valuesCopy);
}
```

Why the method clone() is not visible if the value type is T which is defined as `T extends Cloneable`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The `clone` method is not visible to your code because of the following reasons.

1. The `clone` method is [`protected` in `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--).
2. The [`Cloneable` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) is a marker interface that doesn't guarantee the existence of a `public` `clone` method (or any method).
3. You are using the generic type parameter `T` with the upper bound `Cloneable`, but after type erasure, this becomes just `Cloneable`, so the compiler can only assume `Object` methods exist, and `clone` is protected, so it can't be called this way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clone() in Cloneable.

> Note that this interface does *not* contain the clone
>   method. Therefore, it is not possible to clone an object merely by
>   virtue of the fact that it implements this interface.  Even if the
>   clone method is invoked reflectively, there is no guarantee that it
>   will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

The `clone` method does not work for several reasons as others have noted.

There's a few ways to perform a deep copy on your own, either by literally iterating over your object and copying each element into a new element of the "clones" object, or a quicker way is to `serialize` your object then `deserialize` it... as this will make an exact deep copy.

Here's a quick example that takes any object and will return an exact duplicate object. Make sure you cast back into your expected type.

```
public static Object makeClone(final Object obj) 
                            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
        java.io.ObjectOutputStream obj_out = new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        obj_out.writeObject(obj);

        java.io.ByteArrayInputStream bis = 
                        new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
        java.io.ObjectInputStream obj_in = new java.io.ObjectInputStream(bis);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Object newObj = obj_in.readObject();

        bos.close();
        bis.close();
        obj_out.close();
        obj_in.close();

        return newObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uh sorry, I was convinced that `Cloneable` interface wasn't just a marker interface.

What do you think of my own solution? (I'm not sure that it's correct)

```
public class Column<T extends Copyable<T>> implements Cloneable
{

    private final ArrayList<T> values;

    private String name;

    // ...

    public Column<T> clone()
    {
        ArrayList<T> valuesCopy = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (T value : values)
            valuesCopy.add(value.clone());

        return new Column<T>(name, valuesCopy);
    }

}

public interface Copyable<T> extends Cloneable
{

    public T clone();

}
```

Comment: If you are not sure that it's correct; first try it out, then post.

Comment: Obviously I tried before posting and it works. I'm still not sure if it's a good practice.

Comment: You should make `Column<T>` implement `Copyable<Column<T>>` instead of just `Cloneable`.